# How to change SQL Server collation on an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm running SQL Server 2008R2 Web edition on and EC2 instance. I need to change the server's collation. However, since the installation files are not included in the image, I can't run the setup to rebild databases with the changed collation.

This is a must. Can't work with the default collation.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Amit.

Comment: If you need non standard installation level settings changes you are much better off building your own AMI from a base windows install.

Comment: Well, that will require purchasing of an SQL server license. I need this server for only a limited amount of time, and that is why I went for the EC2 solution. Is there any other way of changing the sql server collation?

Comment: In order to change server level collation you have to rebuild the master DB, which requires sql server installation media. So the short answer is, no you can't change the default collation on an existing ec2 instance. You could potentially place installation media on S3 and reference that to do the rebuild, but I don't know for sure how this would affect the existing license.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: Why is there a need for the installation media? The rebuild of the master DB can be launched by setup.exe from the "Release" subfolder which is already on the C drive.

Comment: By installation media I was referring to setup.exe, which I didn't realize came standard on the image these days. If you've got setup.exe available on the instance, then the rebuild of master should be pretty straightforward provided you don't have any existing DB's. If you have DB's already, you would have to export them and then re-import them after the rebuild. See this link for details on doing the rebuild: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254.aspx